# Android Google Music layout

Tags: android, android-layout, google-music

Good day, I'm new with Android Dev. And I'm starting learning about layouts and soon fragments. I was just wondering, how to do this layout or rather implement it. **The layout at the bottom of the google play app (bottomLayout -  the one that I in circle with red oval).
**Where you can swipe it up to view the album image and the controls (refer to attached img- googlemusicLayout1)**. [googlemusicLayout1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B1D0.png) img2 -
[bottomLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzquh.png)

:) Many thanks in advance. Suggestions will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AndroidSlidingUpPanle library, to achieve your requirement.  And here is the link to that library :- https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/158761)

Comment: @Nigam Patro. - How do I import this one? I'm using ADT (Eclipse).

I tried to import this AndroidSlidingUpPanel, but their is no existing project found. :(   Do you have a sample video for this one? Using/ importing library?
.
or I will just copy all the files from the library? 
.
Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Download the zip file and add it as library to your project.

Comment: Many thanks Nigam Patro . :) Bless by your help.